# type_info referencing deleted function

Tags: c++, types

I'm trying to write a class, that stores configuration items with their name, a description and their types.

OptionItem.h:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>

class OptionItem {
    public:
        OptionItem(std::string name, std::string text, type_info type);
        std::string name() const;
        std::string text() const;
        type_info OptionItem::type() const;
    private:
        std::string _name, _text;
        type_info _type;
};
```

OptionItem.cpp:

```
OptionItem::OptionItem(std::string name, std::string text, type_info type) :
    _name(name), _text(text), _type(type) {};

std::string OptionItem::name() const { return _name; }
std::string OptionItem::text() const { return _text; }
type_info OptionItem::type() const { return _type; }
```

I have a second class that holds the different options:

Opt.h:

```
#include "OptionItem.h"

struct Opt {
    static const OptionItem opt1, opt2;
};
```

Opt.cpp:

```
#include "myOwnClass.h"

const OptionItem Opt::opt1= OptionItem("Option 1", "text1", typeid(std::string));
const OptionItem Opt::opt2= OptionItem("Option 2", "text2", typeid(myOwnClass));
```

A third class that held the actual settings of my program would then look like this:

Settings.h

```
#include "OptionItem"
#include <any>
#include <map>
#include <string>

class Settings {
public:
    void setOption(OptionItem option, std::any value);
    template<class T> T& getOption(const std::string &option) const;

private:
    std::map<std::string, std::any> _options;
}
```

Settings.cpp

```
void Settings::setOption(OptionItem option, std::any value) {
    _options.emplace(option.name(), value);
}

T& Settings::getOption(const std::string &option) const {
    if (_options.find(option) == _options.end()) {
        throw(std::runtime_error("No such option \"" + option + "\"
    }
    else {
        return std::any_cast<T>(_options[option]);
    }
}
```

A call to `Settings::getOption` might look like this:

```
getOption<Opt::opt1.type()>(Opt::opt1.name())
```

I know this has its problems (which is, why I'm asking :-) ) the first one being that `std::type_info` doesn't seem to be copyable. (the compiler(VIsualCPP) tells me `'type_info::type_info(const type_info &)': attempting to reference a deleted function`). The other problem, of which I am sure there are plenty I don't know about since compilation stops with the aforementioned error.

Do you have any suggestions how I could make this work?

Comment: what is the way you want?

Comment: and please add the error messages to the question. If you know there is a problem please share it with us ;)

Comment: are you looking for [`std::type_index`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) ? It wraps a `type_info` and can be copied

Comment: type_index is what I was looking for, thanks. Let's have a look at what else breaks now... :-D